# stm32F1 DMA freezes when using 2 UARTs without any error

Tags: embedded, stm32, microcontroller, nucleo, stm32f1

I am interfacing TFmini S LIDAR with nucleo STM32F103, I am using 2 UARTS, uart1 and uart3 to receive LIDAR data. I am using DMA for that. LIDAR frequency is 1000Hz and data length is 9 bytes. uart 1 and 3 baudrate is set to 256000. I am using HAL_UART_ErrorCallback() function to capture any error.

When I reset the the board by cutting the power off everything works fine. But if I reset it with reset button or software reset one of the uart freezes and I don't see any error. I have checked the error flags nothing in that too.

I tried interrupt based reception without DMA and it doesn't freeze. So its the issue with the DMA but I am not getting any error.

Comment: I recommend you to ask on ST Electronics help forum (if you didn't in mean time)

Comment: If it works from a hard reset but not a soft reset, then that smells like something is not getting initialized correctly.  For example, ensure all the enabled interrupt requests are cleared during startup initialization.

Comment: Are you monitoring the errors detected by the DMA controller? If you aren't, it would be a good place to start.